# URL Mod Rewrite with Region,Country and City

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a Rewrite rule that will do the following:

http://www.domain.com/index.php?region=europe
rewrite like:
http://www.domain.com/europe

http://www.domain.com/index.php?region=europe&country=france
rewrite like:
http://www.domain.com/europe/france

http://www.domain.com/index.php?region=europe&country=france&city=paris
rewrite like:
http://www.domain.com/europe/france/paris

I have absolutely no clue, been trying for a while but not getting what I want.

Anybody that can help me into the right direction?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?region=$1&country=$2&city=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?region=$1&country=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?region=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/(europe)$ index.php?region=$1
RewriteRule ^/(europe)/(france)$ /index.php?region=$1&country=$2
RewriteRule ^/(europe)/(france)/(paris)$ /index.php?region=$1&country=$2&city=$3
```

To make it generic:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ index.php?region=$1
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?region=$1&country=$2
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?region=$1&country=$2&city=$3
```